# CSS - Centering Horizontal Dropdown Navigation

Tags: html, css

I've been looking for the answer to my question, and the majority seem to say use "text-align: center;" and "display:inline-block". However, I still cannot get my drop down menu to center on the page in a responsive manner. I am new to coding, so if you could point me in the right direction it would be awesome.

Here is the HTML for my navigation menu:

```
<nav>
        <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="#">Skating</a>
                <ul class="skating">
                    <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Special Sessions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Discount Coupons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Skating Lessons</a></li>
                </ul></li>
           <li><a href="#">Party Info</a>
                <ul class="partyinfo">
                    <li><a href="#">Birthday Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Private Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Adult Skate Party</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fundraisers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Party Forms</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">Roller Hockey</a>
                <ul class="hockey">
                    <li><a href="#">7-10 Year Old</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">11-14 Year Old</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">League Information</a></li>
                </ul></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul class="about">
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Directions</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
                </ul></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

And here is the CSS file corresponding to the HTML file

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

header {
text-align: center;
}



ul#nav li {
width: 125px;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
margin-right:5px;
float: left;
line-height: 25px;
border-radius: 10px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
}

ul#nav a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width: 125px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

ul#nav, ul.skating, ul.partyinfo, ul.hockey, ul.about {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1em;

}

ul#nav li:hover > a {
background-color: yellow;
}

ul#nav ul.skating, ul.partyinfo, ul.hockey, ul.about {
display:none;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.skating {
display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.partyinfo {
display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.hockey {
display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.about {
display: block;
}


img.header {
float:right;
}
```

Sorry for the basic question, but all help is appreciated. If you see any other issues with my code, feel free to let me know so I can continue to improve.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you want on window resize(reduce) the menu items to go below and the whole menu to be centered?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the basics. You need to to use absolute position on the submenus and apply `text-align:center` to the parent ul

[**JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/u7JrQ/2/)

HTML - unchanged

CSS

```
* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}

ul#nav {
 text-align: center;
 vertical-align:top;
}

ul#nav li {
width: 125px;
position: relative;
margin-right:5px;
line-height: 25px;
border-radius: 10px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 5px;
}

ul#nav a {
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
width: 125px;
height: 25px;
line-height: 25px;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

ul.skating, ul.partyinfo, ul.hockey, ul.about {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
font-size: 1em;

position: absolute;
top:100%;

}

ul#nav li:hover > a {
background-color: yellow;
}

ul#nav ul.skating, ul.partyinfo, ul.hockey, ul.about {
display:none;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.skating {
display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.partyinfo {
display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.hockey {
display: block;
}

ul#nav li:hover ul.about {
display: block;
```

You would so well to use less ID tags and use re-usable classes instead on the submenus.